# Unexpected Token - MODX Revolution 2.2.9

Tags: token, modx

Almost everything I do in the manager of my website in MODX, I keep getting this error:

```
Unexpected token <:
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@(mydomain).com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

I can not edit my website with MODX or do anything with this. Does anyone have any fixes or suggestions to fix this?

Thank you, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a corrupted file - did you edit any of the core files in the manager folder? 
if it's every page and only in the manager [the site works fine?] :

1. check your server error log, it probably tells you exactly which file to look in.
2. check the manager/config.core.php & manager/index.php for syntax & errors
3. check core/config/config.inc.php for syntax & errors

If you don't find anything - update to 2.2.10 & hopefully that will overwrite the offending file.

Comment: I have updated it to 2.2.10 and am still getting the same error. Do you have any other suggestions as to what it could be?

Comment: did you try everything else? anything in the server or modx logs?

Answer (score 0):

Check your resource usage for your installation - specifically hitting virtual memory limits.

After many attempts to track down this problem on my Revo installation and getting nowhere I have come to the conclusion that this error is due to hitting virtual memory limits on my hosting package. Unfortunately I'd have to upgrade to a VPS package to increase my limits with my existing provider so I haven't been able to confirm this yet.